# Master's student without internship or publications in final semester; how to accomplish something worth putting on my resume?

Tags: thesis, india

I am a 3<sup>rd</sup>-year Masters CSE student. Since I am a 3<sup>rd</sup>-year student, my advisor has asked me to work on my thesis since 1<sup>st</sup> year. I picked a problem and worked very hard for around 1.5 years only to realise that nothing new could be done out of it. I have asked my advisor multiple times to let me go for some internships, but he doesn't allow it, telling me that I should get some research output first.

The problem is that he doesn't really have a good problem statement to work on. I am in my final semester now and I have no accomplishments like a research paper or any internship experience. He doesn't have any collaborations either. I am very depressed because I worked so hard reading multiple research papers but now I have nothing on my resume.

**Question:**  What could I do to avoid graduating at the end of the semester without accomplishing anything worth putting on my resume?

Comment: What is your location? This sounds very different to how a masters works where I did it, so I suspect good answers would be based on knowing the system you are currently in.

Comment: To the OP, please use your account to sign in and specify your location. To the user who suggested the edit, please do not guess the OP's location. We need the OP to tell us his/her location. Thanks.

Comment: I want to be anonymous, so I have changed my original name. I am from India.

Comment: Tag added based on new info given by OP in an answer

Comment: See [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) - please merge your accounts so that you can edit your question and respond to comments.

Comment: Talk to your department chair.